# XSL: name a tag with a name dependent on the input xml content

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

I have defined a variable $myVar (meaning that the following xsl):

```
<xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
```

gives as output:

```
NiceStr
```

I want to create a tag:

```
<NiceStr/>
```

in a sense I would write something of this kind:

```
<<xsl:value-of select="$myVar">/>
```

which, obviously, doesn't work.

How to name a tag with a name dependent on the input xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:element name="{$myVar}"/>
```

The `{}` is an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) so the `$myVar` gets evaluated.